# how to determine the whether we are using web1.0 or 2.0?

Tags: java, web

i am working on a java-struts based project. I really don't know how to find whether it is on `web 1.o or 2.0.`
how to find it and where can we look for the definition like the version.

Please help .

Regards

Comment: `web 2.0` was a marketing name for "we use lots of ajax". Maybe you are refering to servlet version?

Comment: Yes, this project is based on many ajax (`DWR`) calls, is that means web 2.0,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the `property` of your project. And there you have a `tab` on the left panel called `Project Facets`. You can click on that to see what all technology have you configured, along with their versions.

Comment: I am using netbeans IDE, Java 1.7 and struts 1.2.9,dwr.and JSP for front view.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page on Web 2.0 on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0).

Web 2.0 is really just a convenient label for a different way of thinking about the web.  The key idea is that the web is a platform for building application, rather than just being a way to deliver content to end users.

It is certainly not a fixed set of technologies, and it is certainly not something that you can detect or test ... or compare against a set of standards.

Comment: Now i understood by going through this link, very useful :)